# How to remove an old email link from an event page

Tags: civievent

I have created a new event page and on the online registration page I have entered the 'Confirm From email' address that I want to use. However, when someone registers for the event the confirmation email is being sent to a different email address that was used for an event in 2018. This alternative email address was listed as disabled on the 'From email addresses' list and I have since deleted it but messages are still being sent to it from this new event page. I can't find anywhere in the CiviCRM system where this email address exists to change or delete this association with the event page.
Where can I look to edit or delete this association?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question.  Confirmation emails are supposed to go to the registrant, not a fixed email address.  Is this a bcc: address?  Could you please edit your question to clarify?  Also, could you check **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions** to see if you have the "CiviRules" extension installed?  That could change the answer to the question.

Comment: The registrant is getting a confirmation email and I have entered email addresses into the cc and bcc boxes to go to the email addresses I want- all of which is happening correctly but in addition the confimration email is also being sent to another email address set up for an event in 2018 which I haven't entered on the event page and I can't find listed anywhere else on the system (other than as an inactive 'from email' address which I have deleted). I can't see a CiviRules extension listed in the system settings. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your help.
I have now fixed the problem- it was hiding on a profile page for conference registrants in the advanced settings section at the bottom of the page (which I had missed!)

Answer (score 3):

I can think of three possibilities. Let's call the email address that is erroneously receiving these emails the "mystery email address".

1. Your payment processor is configured with the mystery email address for notification. If this is the answer, then the emails you are getting would be not from CiviCRM and you'll probably be able to see that from the contents.
2. When creating the event, you copied/cloned the previous event, and the address was somehow carried along in a field that you're no longer seeing.
3. One of the email addresses that is being notified (correctly) has been configured to automatically forward a copy to the mystery email address.

To further diagnose the issue, take a look at the email headers of one of the emails that you received to the mystery email address. It will show you some details about which address is was originally sent to, as well as where it originated from.